# Why is Plex Media Server not working for me on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plex

I want to start by stating that I have used Plex Media Server several times in the past on Ubuntu 16.  There are multiple different approaches to installing Plex on Ubuntu 16 desktop.  I have tried downloading the installer, adding a plex.list to my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.  I followed two different instructions, one approach described in a course on using Raspberry Pi as a home server.

In all cases it appears to install ok, although at times, it returns a status 1 error from the install script.  So, the next step after install would be to browse to localhost:32400/web/ and setup my media sources.  I guess it is obvious that this wouldn't work if it was returning an error from the installer.

I thought I'd be better at getting things done on Linux since moving from Windows to Ubuntu for my desktop environment.  However, I am unable to find where the error exists or why it is problematic.

I did check firewall status, as well as my router - making sure port 32400 was open.  Maybe there is a docker hub version?

Thanks in advance for any tips,
Bruce

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/ , since stackoverflow is for programming questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel embarrassed to admit that the problem was that I was using an incomplete url.  I was using https://localhost:32400/
I was missing the web sub-directory.  I guess I thought it would redirect.  Hopefully, I am not the only one to have made such a silly mistake.
Anyway, if I had put into the address bar: http://localhost:32400/web/
( or if I do this now ), I get to the same screen that would be needed for setting up one's libraries of movies, music, pics etc.
Bruce